# Permission denied - mkdir / No write access for G

Tags: linux, files, permissions

I have a root folder with the permissions as

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

All the folders that are in the root directory has the same permissions.

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

I have a PHP script which creates a PDF file on the Server (Which is on one of the folders in the root directory) and because of the limited permissions am unable to create the pdf file in the folder.

I wanted to Change the Access permissions of the Folder and tried the below command

```
chmod g+w Images     (Images is a folder)
```

It executes and gives me nothing and when I try

```
ls -l   (The permissions are same and it didn't change)
drwxr-xr-x   (The write permissions are missing to generate the pdf file)
```

When I try

```
mkdir -m 775 imagetest
```

It Returns me with "mkdir: cannot Change permissions of 'imagetest': Permission denied"

The Imagetest Folder is created with the same permissions as

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

Can anyone help me out here. I was struck at this Point on changing the folder permissions.

From the comments, when I try

```
ls -ld Images 
drwxr-xr-x 1 ZUHTRF6 1049089 0 May 25
```

Comment: Please don't chop parts out of your directory permissions. In the directory above `Images`, where you run `chmod g+w Images`, please then run the command `ls -ld Images` and put the result in your question.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: You've chopped off part of the result of `ls -ld` again. Please stop doing that and instead put the entire result in your question. Presumably up next to your `chmod g+w Images` command?

Comment: I can't follow what you're doing in what directory. But in any case, as the owner of the new directory, you _should_ be able to change its permissions. What filesystem are you running? Is there anything else that would be in any way special with the filesystem or directory tree?

Answer (score 1):

When changing permission of a folder already existing you should use `chmod xxx yourFolder/`. You can do this recursivly by adding -R.

Check with which user you are logged in using `whoami` and compare it with the user displayed from `ls -l`, to see if your current user is allowed do make a permission change.

Using `chmod g+w file` adds write permission for the group.

You could also do this with `sudo` if you are root, but watch out that you know what the commands are doing :)

Comment: Hello, both the users are same. The user logged in and the user from the ls -l are same. chmod g+w file is not working in my case. when I try sudo it says command not found

Comment: Even the chmod 775 filename is not changing the folder permissions

Comment: Have you checked if you are logged in with the correct user (in that case it would be `ZUHTRF6` case-sensitive!).

If you are already at the point where you try to call the PHP script, are you doing it from the CLI - or from the browser through a webserver which is running under a different user.

Strange that sudo isn't found, what distro are you using?

Like roaima said we really need you to show us the FULL error logs / outputs of commands, otherwise we could easily oversee something ;)
Also take a read on chmod and how UNIX permissions are handled. No offense.

Comment: Am running from the browser through a webserver which is running under a different user. I use git server

Comment: @john please put these updates in your question. Not in comments. Remember you should be wanting to make it as easy as possible for people to read and understand your question!